# TypeScript Picking Type

Tags: typescript

I would like to extract and use "body" from "sampleType" below.

```
export type NOT_CONTENT = "";
export type sampleType =
  | {
      id: number;
      friends: {
        id: number;
        icon: string;
        birthday: string;
        gender: string;
        created_at: string;
        updated_at: string;
      };
      message: {
        body:
          | {
              type: "text";
              text_message: {
                text: string;
              };
            }
          | {
              type: "action";
              action_message: {
                text: string;
              };
            }
          | {
              type: "";
            };
        id: number;
      };
      unread_status: boolean;
    }
  | NOT_CONTENT;
```

I tried the pick below, but it doesn't work.

```
Pick<sampleType, "body">
```

What methods are there? Please teach me..

Comment: Exclude the `""` and then access it: `Exclude<sampleType, NOT_CONTENT>["message"]["body"]`

Comment: @Sophia - "body" is not a immediate member in your `type`. 
`Pick<sampleType["message"], "body">` would work